# Better PHP with Json

Tags: php, html, json, zend-framework

Hi currently i have an app on Zend php framework, and i heavily using json to fetch data from controller. Now i am not sure whether the way i parse json data into hmtl within javascript are good or not. Below are my sample code.

controller:

```
public function searchAction()
    {
        $search = $this->getRequest()->getParam('search');
        $user = new Application_Model_User();
        $userMapper = new Application_Model_Mapper_UserMapper();

        $usersearch = $userMapper->findByString($search);

        for($i=0; $i<count($usersearch); $i++)
        {
            $usersearch[$i]['pic'] = $this->view->getLoginUserImage($usersearch[$i]['social_id'],$usersearch[$i]['login_type'],null,null,square);
        }
          $this->_helper->json($usersearch);

    }
```

View: member.phtml

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="clearfix page-header">
        <h1 class="heading">Member Search</h1>
    </div>

<div class="clearfix layout-block layout-a">
<div class="column column-alpha member-search-container">
                <div class="search-input-container clearfix">

            <form action="/member_search?query=" class="member-search-form" id="member-search-form" method="get" name="member_search_form" data-component-bound="true">

                        <fieldset>
                            <legend>Member Search</legend>
                            <label for="name_field">
                                <strong>    Name</strong>
                            </label>
                            <span class="formNote">
                                    (e.g. Bob Smith, Bob S.)
                            </span><br>
                            <input type="hidden" name="action_search" value="Search">
                            <input class="name-field" id="story-title" name="query" size="90" type="text" placeholder="search" autocomplete="off" style="width:220px;">
                            <div id="search-box"></div>
                            <div class="auto-name" style="display: none;"></div>
                        </fieldset>

</form>         


                </div>
                <div class="member-search-results">
                </div>

</div>

</div>

</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){

});



$('#story-title').keyup(function(e){
    var searchbox = $(this).val();

    if(searchbox == '')
    {
        $(".similar_story_block").hide();
    }else {

    $.ajax({
        url:"<?= $this->baseUrl('index/search')?>",
        data:{'search':$('#story-title').val()},
        dataType:"json",
        type:"POST",
        cache:false,
        success:function(data){
            if(data.length > 0)
            {
                        var divHtml = '<div class="similar_story_block" style="display: block;">'+
                        '<div class="head">'+
                        '<p>People</p>'+
                        '<a href="#" id="close-element-form" onclick="javascript:closeSearchBoxMember(event)"></a>'+
                        '</div>'+
                        '<ul>';

                       for(var count=0; count<data.length;count++)
                       {
                            if(data[count]['reviews_num'] != null )
                            {
                                 data[count]['reviews_num']
                            }
                            else 
                            {
                                data[count]['reviews_num'] = 0
                            }

                            divHtml+='<li>'+

                            '<a class="pushstate no-confirm" href="' + baseUrl + 'user/' + data[count]['user_unique_name'] + '">'+
                            '<div class="image">'+
                            '<img alt="" src="'+data[count]['pic']+'">'+
                            '</div>'+
                            '<div class="fleft col-400">'+
                            '<p>'+ data[count]['name'] +'</p>'+
                            '<span>'+data[count]['reviews_num']+' Reviews</span>'+
                            '</div>'+
                            '</a>'+
                            '</li>';                        
                       }
                        divHtml += '</ul></div>';
                        $("#search-box").html(divHtml);
                        $(".search-box").show();                        


            }
            else {
                         $("#search-box").html('');
                        $(".search-box").hide();
            }
        }
    }) }
});

    function closeSearchBox(event)
    {
        disabledEventPreventDefault(event);
        $(".similar_story_block").hide();
    }



</script>
```

Currently the above code will do a live query of members who already signup to the site. The code work very well, but i am not sure if this is right way of doing. Below is how it looks on chrome debug console

[image: console debug]

it seems i am exposing too much of details. It would be appreciated if anyone can suggest a better way of fetch a data from controller, or how it can be done by using partial template.
Thanks for your help !!!

Comment: You could have it return an html view rather than data. So the controller could fetch the view and parse data into it and then echo it to your ajax callback.

Comment: yes how can i do that..? i need an sample for the above code in effective way..

Comment: @zlippr: please don't use the word "effective" in cases when you don't even have ineffective solution.

Comment: @zerkms so it means my solution is effective to use?

Comment: as for the above question on `good or not` well it depends on your priorities, having to put your result on json means that the data passed will be compact(therefore save on bandwidth) ie, have you seen how facebook manages its feeds? on the other hand you'd return an html, it would be much simpler as just to append it directly

Comment: @lanace so what do you think about the above code snippet?

Answer (score 1):

You can either render your template via PHP and send HTML down the wire, or you can send JSON and render your template using JavaScript.

I would suggest the latter using something like [HandlebarsJS](http://handlebarsjs.com/).

Define the HTML template:

```
<script id="member-template" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
  <p>Name: {{ name }}</p>
  <p>Role: {{ role }}</p>
</script>
```

Our example JSON data:

```
var data = {"name": "Bob", "role": "Manager"};
```

Render our template with our JSON data:

```
var template = Handlebars.compile($("#member-template").html());
var html     = template(data);
```

The `html` variable will be your compiled HTML that you can insert witin your `<div class="member-search-results">` div.

Comment: Why do you suggest rendering with JS? You're relying on the client to properly parse it and are assuming the user has JS enabled. This is an actual question by the way, not trying to criticize you.

Comment: There is a risk that the client won't have JS enabled, but that would be an incredibly small number of users. And the original poster is asking about how to properly render JSON data via JavaScript anyway.

Comment: yes. That is my question, if it is possible i would like to build an html along with data in controller and render it to view through JSON.

Answer (score 0):

I think if your project has a lot of visitors and this operation uses often you can relay this function to them. It's could reduce little load on the server. But it could work only if you have very many visitors (pageview). But if your project not so big you can't feel the difference and "PHP way" could be easier on my mind.